# SQL: Creating Tables using CTEs

Tags: sql, netezza

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following SQL code:

```
create table sample1(
var1 integer,
var2 integer
);

insert into sample1(var1,var2)
values(1,1);
insert into sample1(var1,var2)
values(2,2);


create table sample2(
var1 integer,
var2 integer
);

insert into sample2(var1,var2)
values(3,3);
insert into sample2(var1,var2)
values(4,4);


select * from sample1
union all
select * from sample2;
```

**My Question:** Is it possible to combine this SQL into a single statement that runs start to finish (e.g. CTE based)? The reason I am interested in this because I don't have to delete tables sample1, sample2 after.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: One single statement can only INSERT into one table.

Comment: Have you considered using TEMPORARY tables? Take a look at CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE syntax: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=npsscr-create-table

You could also try BEGIN transactions: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=npsscr-begin

Comment: Temp tables or Table variables is what you are looking for, just like anask commented

Answer (score 2):

What Joel San has written is almost correct

You can define `sample1` and `sample2` as CTEs and then union the results of the two. Here's how you can do that:

```sql
WITH sample1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS var1, 1 AS var2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 2
),
sample2 AS (
    SELECT 3 AS var1, 3 AS var2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 4
)

SELECT * FROM sample1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM sample2;
```

Comment: This will give you the combined result set of sample1 and sample2 without actually creating and inserting data into physical tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much familiar with Netezza, but most database products have some variant of table-value constructors. In SQL Server, it would let you do something like this:

```
with sample1 as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (VALUES 
        (1, 1),
        (2, 2)
    ) s(var1, var2)
),
sample2 as (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES
        (3, 3),
        (4, 4)
    ) s(var1, var2)
)
select * from sample1
union all
select * from sample2;
```

> https://dbfiddle.uk/Ngun8G5R

MySQL would look almost the same, but it needs the `row` keyword added before each tuple. Again, I'm not sure what the Netezza variant will look like. I did find a reference indicating Netezza is based on Postgresql, in which case the code above works at least as far back as Postgresql 9.3.

But I'm struggling to see how this is a good idea relative to just having the whole thing as a single table-value constructor or (better yet) actually creating a real table (not a temp table) to hold this data.

Comment: @ Joel Coehoorn: thank you so much for your answer, unfortunately this did not work from my side

Comment: I am trying to get the error that came

Comment: The reason I am interested in this because I don't have to delete tables sample1, sample2 after. .... its a very tiring process to create and delete these tables again and again

Comment: `"... don't have to delete tables ... "` Again, it seems like the better approach is actually defining all this as part of the permanent formal schema for the application.

Comment: Are you able to share the error you are getting from netezza?

Comment: @stats_noob , I'm a bit unclear about your objective. Are you attempting to insert only four records into those two tables?

In Netezza SQL, the Values clause is not allowed I would think. I think you may use the UNION ALL operator to combine the results from the sample1 and sample2 CTEs. Here's the equivalent Netezza SQL code:

`WITH sample1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS var1, 1 AS var2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS var1, 2 AS var2
),
sample2 AS (
    SELECT 3 AS var1, 3 AS var2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS var1, 4 AS var2
)
SELECT * FROM sample1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM sample2;
`

Answer (score 1):

> The reason I am interested in this because I don't have to delete tables sample1, sample2 after. .... its a very tiring process to create and delete these tables again and again

In Netezza, you can achieve your goal without creating and inserting data multiple times by creating views for your tables and then performing the UNION ALL operation on those views.

```
-- Create view for sample1
  create view sample1_view as
  select * from (
  select 1 as var1, 1 as var2
  union all
  select 2 as var1, 2 as var2
  ) v;

-- Create view for sample2
  create view sample2_view as
  select * from (
  select 3 as var1, 3 as var2
  union all
  select 4 as var1, 4 as var2
  ) v;

-- Query to combine data from sample1_view and sample2_view using UNION ALL

  with combined_data as (
  select * from sample1_view
  union all
  select * from sample2_view
  )
  select * from combined_data;
```